# Using Unicode with PHP

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

How do I use **Unicode** with **PHP**?

I want to store Unicode value in a PHP **variable** but it output some **question marks**.

What is the **solution**?

Comment: It might be as simple as your browser not displaying the Unicode characters correctly because you have not set utf-8 as the encoding.

Comment: Unicode is just a standard (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). What exactly do you mean by *Unicode*?

Comment: @Saiful: Accept some questions first.

Comment: It is not required to accept answers before asking new questions. But if some of your answers had been satisfactorily answered, please accept the respective answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something you're going to have to read up on to do correctly, but here are two links you should start with:
[Character Sets / Character Encoding Issues](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets)
[Handling UTF-8 with PHP](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8)

Comment: Thanks, those are very good links! The issue is much more complicated than just setting the header

Answer (score 8):

In php.ini:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding = "UTF-8"

; overload(replace) single byte functions by mbstring functions.
; mail(), ereg(), etc are overloaded by mb_send_mail(), mb_ereg(),
; etc. Possible values are 0,1,2,4 or combination of them.
; For example, 7 for overload everything.
; 0: No overload
; 1: Overload mail() function
; 2: Overload str*() functions
; 4: Overload ereg*() functions
mbstring.func_overload = 4
```

Answer (score 4):

make sure your output encoding is utf8

```
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

PS accept some answers.